# How to determine the correct file encoding for use with read.fwf (or use a workaround to remove non-conforming characters)

Tags: r, character-encoding

I tried the approach in the following question and am still stuck.

[How to detect the right encoding for read.csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv)

This following code should be reproduceable...  Any ideas?  I'd rather not use scan() or readLines because I've been using this code successfully for assorted state level ACS data in the past....

My other thought is to edit the text file prior to importing it.  However I store the files zipped and use a script to unzip and then access the data.  Having to edit the file outside of the R environment would really gum up that process.  Thanks in advance!

```
Filename <- "g20095us.txt"
Url <- "http://www2.census.gov/acs2005_2009_5yr/summaryfile/2005-2009_ACSSF_By_State_By_Sequence_Table_Subset/UnitedStates/All_Geographies_Not_Tracts_Block_Groups/"

Widths <- c(6,2,3,2,7,1,1,1,2,2,3,5,5,6,1,5,4,5,1,3,5,5,5,3,5,1,1,5,3,5,5,5,2,3,
        3,6,3,5,5,5,5,5,1,1,6,5,5,40,200,6,1,50)
Classes <- c(rep('character',4),'integer',rep('character',47))
Names <- c('fileid','stusab','sumlev','geocomp','logrecno','us','region','division',
       'statece','state','county','cousub','place','tract','blkgrp','concit',
       rep('blank',14),'ua',rep('blank',11),'ur',rep('blank',4),'geoid','name',rep('blank',3))
GeoHeader <- read.fwf(paste0(Url,Filename),widths=Widths,
                  colClasses=Classes,col.names=Names,fill=TRUE,strip.white=TRUE)
```

Four lines from the file "g2009us.txt" below.  The second one "Canoncito" is causing the problems.  The other files in the download are csv but this one is fixed-width and necessary to identify geographies of interest (the organization of the data is not very intuitive).

ACSSF US251000000964                                2430      090                                                                                                                 25100US2430090                          Cameron Chapter, Navajo Nation Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AZ--NM--UT
ACSSF US251000000965                                2430      092                                                                                                                 25100US2430092                          Cañoncito Chapter, Navajo Nation Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AZ--NM--UT
ACSSF US251000000966                                2430      095                                                                                                                 25100US2430095                          Casamero Lake Chapter, Navajo Nation Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AZ--NM--UT
ACSSF US251000000967                                2430      105                                                                                                                 25100US2430105                          Chi Chil Tah Chapter, Navajo Nation Reservation and Off-Reservation Trust Land, AZ--NM--UT

Comment: So thats a big file! But I grabbed one from DC and looked at it... they look like comma separated files rather than fixed width.  They also read in just fine using `read.csv`.  If I'm wrong, post the first few lines from the `g20095us.txt` file in your question so we can avoid the big download

Comment: Thanks Justin.  I forgot that one can directly access the file rather than downloading the entire set of data. The code has been updated to point directly at the file in question (which is the only fixed width file in the zipped set I linked to previously).

Comment: I find it easiest to use a text editor like `emacs` or a command line tool like `sed` to clean up fixed width files to a more manageable format (e.g. tsv or csv).  However, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806823/how-to-detect-the-right-encoding-for-read-csv) for more details on determining file encoding

Comment: Yeah.  I posted the same link at the beginning of the post.  And I didn't get any closer after working through the author's suggestions.  I might have implemented it incorrectly though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we start by identifying all non-ASCII characters. I do this by converting
converting to a raw vector, and then looking for values over 127 (the last 
unambiguously encoded value in ASCII).

```
lines <- readLines("g20095us.txt")

non_ascii <- function(x) {
  any(charToRaw(x) > 127)
}

bad <- vapply(lines, non_ascii, logical(1), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
lines[bad]
```

We then need to figure out what the correct encoding is. This is challenging
when we only have two cases, and often involves some trial and error. In this 
case I googled for "encoding \xf1", and discovered 
[Why doesn't this conversion to utf8 work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163485),  which suggested that latin1 might 
be the corect encoding.

I tested that using `iconv` which converts from one encoding to another (and
you always want to use utf-8):

```
iconv(lines[bad], "latin1", "utf-8")
```

Finally, we reload with the correct encoding. Confusingly, the encoding
argument to any of the `read.*` functions doesn't do this - you need to 
manually specify an encoding on the connection:

```
fixed <- readLines(file("g20095us.txt", encoding = "latin1"))
fixed[bad]
```