# Why R gsub (or regexp) for punctuation doesn't get all punctuation?

Tags: regex, r, character-encoding

I am working on cleaning up a text-based data file and cannot figure out how why the `gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", X1)` is not giving a match for all punctuation.  Unfortunately, I cannot replicate the problem here, which makes me think it is a character encoding issue -- the punctuation in question have an appearance that is obviously different from standard ASCII.

Is this a problem that I can solve after reading in the files, or do I have to do something at the front end?  For example, Hadley's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496059/how-to-determine-the-correct-file-encoding-for-use-with-read-fwf-or-use-a-worka) on an encoding issue makes me think that I need to specifying the encoding statement when I read the files.  However, I am reading a bunch of different txt files from a folder, so I am not sure the best solution.  Basically, I just want to retain all letters [A-Za-z] and exclude everything else.  (That said, `gsub([^A-Za-z], "", X1)` doesn't work either!)

Any suggestions on handling this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can define your own character classes with whatever punctuation you need or what it is not getting `gsub('[.,:]', '', '.,:?;')` would that work?

Comment: I think that could work, but the solution doesn't scale.  I have a bunch of different characters in the different format that need to be addressed.  My hope is something that would essentially discard every single character that is not a letter.

Comment: then that would be `gsub('\\W', '', 'fasdfa.,:asdf?;adfa')`, correct?

Comment: â€œâ€” This is what I am trying to figure out! The solutions aren't grabbing those characters ...

Comment: ah. that's not punctuation

Comment: What is it about `gsub("[^A-Za-z]", "", X1)` that "doesn't work"? It seemed to "work" well when I tried it on your counter-example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the punctuation character is out of the ascii range. By default `[[:punct:]]` contains only ascii punctuation characters. But you can extend the class to unicode with the `(*UCP)` directive. But this doesn't suffice, you need to inform the regex engine that it must read the target string as an utf encoded string with `(*UTF)` *(otherwise a multibyte encoded character will be seen as several one byte characters)*. So:

```
gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)[[:punct:]]", "", X1, perl=T)
```

Note: these two directives exist only in perl mode and must be at the very begining of the pattern.

Note2: you can do the same like this:

```
gsub("(*UTF)\\pP+", "", X1, perl=T)
```

Because `\pP` is a shorthand for all unicode punctation characters, `(*UCP)` becomes useless.

Comment: Excellent explanation for a very useful capability!  Thank you.