# Cannot gsub UTF-8 symbols

Tags: r, utf-8, gsub

I have a character string in UTF-8, and need to 1) `gsub` special symbols, 2) convert whole data frame to "normal" (ASCII?) encoding. However, I fail to run `gsub` on it - doesn't catch the string. 
I work in `French` locale (tried UTF-8) but didn't get it granted.
Cannot give you the full dataset, but will post a couple strings from it here.

```
  DataFrame = read.csv("SLD_products_FullData.csv",header=F,sep=",",encoding = "UTF-8")
  title = DataFrame$title
```

This is how title looks like in console:

```
"Campbellâ€™s Gravy and General Mills â€¢ Cheerios"
```

And in Viewer:

```
Campbell’s Gravy and General Mills • Cheerios"
```

Tried (with all kinds of perl, fixed, etc):

```
gsub("â€™","'",title)
gsub("â€¢","-",title)
```

Even tried `gsub("’","'",title)`. No luck.

```
Encoding(title)
[1] "UTF-8"
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: your gsub command works for me.

Comment: Hmm... when I copy/paste the above text it does indeed work. But not in the original code/file encoding.

Comment: Your `gsub` command works for me too, however, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28976569/why-r-gsub-or-regexp-for-punctuation-doesnt-get-all-punctuation) shows how to specify UTF encoding in a regex using `gsub`, so maybe that will help resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. Are you referring to `UPC` etc? I tried: `> title[8]
[1] "Campbellâ€™s Gravy"
> gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)â€™","--",title[8])
[1] "Campbellâ€™s Gravy"`

Comment: One more comment - copy/pasting from this page works, as encoding becomes correct. The original setup doesn't work. Any suggestions to how I can post here the file with sample string (cannot post full file for data copyright reasons)

Answer (score 0):

```
title <- "Campbellâ€™s Gravy and General Mills â€¢ Cheerios"
Encoding(title) 
#In your case it should be UTF-8

#iconvlist() to list possible encodings
#iconv to change encoding from latin1 to UTF-8
title <- iconv(title, "latin1", "UTF-8")
Encoding(title)
[1] "UTF-8"

#Apply Native encoding on the vector    
title <- enc2native(title)
Encoding(title)
[1] "latin1"

#Apply UTF8 encoding on the vector  
title <- enc2utf8(title)
Encoding(title)
[1] "UTF-8"

# Force a change in the encoding
Encoding(title) <- "latin1"
Encoding(title)
[1] "latin1"

title <- enc2utf8(title)
title2 <- gsub("â€¢","-",title)
title2 <- gsub("â€™","'",title2)
title2
[1] "Campbell's Gravy and General Mills - Cheerios"

Encoding(title2)
[1] "unknown"

title2 <- gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)â€¢","--",title, perl= TRUE)
title2 <- gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)â€™","'",title2, perl= TRUE)
title2
[1] "Campbell's Gravy and General Mills -- Cheerios"
Encoding(title2)
[1] "unknown"
```

"Unknown" is any other encoding than latin1, UTF-8, or bytes. [See](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/1.5.0_may_2013/TERR_1.5.0_LanguageRef/base/Encoding.html)

Comment: I tried. Here's the part of the code: `print(title[8])
print(Encoding(title[8]))
title2 <- gsub("â€™","-",title[8])
print(title2)
`       result is: `[1] "Campbellâ€™s Gravy"
[1] "UTF-8"
[1] "Campbellâ€™s Gravy"`

Comment: P.S. how do I put caret end in a comment so the code in the comment looks like one in an answer?

Comment: Maybe: title2 <- gsub((enc2utf8("â€™","'",title2))) or title2 <- gsub("(*UCP)(*UTF)â€™","'",title2, perl= TRUE). Sorry I can't help further. Everything works perfectly here.